# Delay Binding in Android

Tags: mvvmcross

I am programatically generating the UI and doing the binding in OnCreateView and there is a noticeable delay before the view renders on screen.

I would like to know if it would be possible to delay the binding so that the controls are rendered first and the binding follows. Please advise suitable function where I can do this.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            var fragmentView = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var linearLayout = fragmentView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

            BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(Activity, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(inflater), ViewModel);
            using (new MvxBindingContextStackRegistration<IMvxAndroidBindingContext>(
                ((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext)))
            {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ArticleFragment, ArticleFragmentViewModel>();

                // Name field (one of many fields...
                set.Bind(InflateEditableText(inflater, linearLayout, "Name"))
                    .For(v => v.Text)
                    .To(vm => vm.Item.Name)
                    .WithConversion("TrimmableString");
                InflateAndBindValidationText(inflater, linearLayout, set, "Validator.Messages['Name']");

                //
                // Other fields follow... same pricinple as Name field
                //

                set.Apply();
            }

            return fragmentView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I have also refactored the code to do all the bindings in a task, but i'm getting *intermittent* errors related to some "collection changed" (can't remember the exact error). The idea was to have the layout done by the ui thread and the binding done on a separate thread, and to to task.Wait() before set.Apply(). It works, but intermittently fails.

EDIT: Added trace.

```
FIRST RUN (2248 ms)

[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 16.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 16.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
06-04 16:17:35.244 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 16.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
06-04 16:17:35.729 I/Choreographer(26420): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 17.70 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 17.70 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
06-04 16:17:36.059 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 17.70 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 17.72 Adding subscription 0556b442-e560-49d2-934d-74a9e703d43d for ArticleEditDoneMsg
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 17.72 Adding subscription 0556b442-e560-49d2-934d-74a9e703d43d for ArticleEditDoneMsg
06-04 16:17:36.069 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 17.72 Adding subscription 0556b442-e560-49d2-934d-74a9e703d43d for ArticleEditDoneMsg
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 17.73 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 17.73 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
06-04 16:17:36.094 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 17.73 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
06-04 16:17:36.249 D/Mono    (26420): Remapped public key token of retargetable assembly System from 7cec85d7bea7798e to b77a5c561934e089
06-04 16:17:36.249 D/Mono    (26420): The request to load the retargetable assembly System v2.0.5.0 was remapped to System v2.0.0.0
06-04 16:17:36.299 D/Mono    (26420): Unloading image System.dll [0x5cfefdc8].
06-04 16:17:36.309 D/Mono    (26420): Image addref System[0x5d017280] -> System.dll[0x59d2ab60]: 16
06-04 16:17:36.309 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref FluentValidation[0x5932fe90] -> System[0x59d2b6e0]: 15
06-04 16:17:36.524 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref Hlx.Mpos.Core[0x58214730] -> System.Collections[0x58246718]: 5
06-04 16:17:36.614 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref Hlx.Mpos.Core[0x58214730] -> System.Interactive[0x5935eb78]: 2
06-04 16:17:36.619 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref System.Interactive[0x5935eb78] -> System.Runtime[0x592cd8d8]: 9
06-04 16:17:36.619 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref System.Interactive[0x5935eb78] -> System.Resources.ResourceManager[0x592c8c20]: 8
[0:] 
mvx:Warning: 18.30 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
[0:] mvx:Warning: 18.30 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:17:36.659 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Warning: 18.30 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:17:36.874 D/Mono    (26420): Assembly Ref addref Hlx.Mpos.Droid[0x41c96980] -> Hlx.Net.Extensions[0x5821e218]: 3
[0:] 
mvx:Warning: 18.58 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
[0:] mvx:Warning: 18.58 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:17:36.934 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Warning: 18.58 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:17:37.294 W/ResourceType(26420): getEntry failing because entryIndex 66 is beyond type entryCount 1
Thread started:  #6
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 19.77 Wait starting for 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 19.77 Wait starting for 
06-04 16:17:38.134 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 19.77 Wait starting for 
Thread started:  #7
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic: 19.91 Wait starting for 
06-04 16:17:38.259 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic: 19.91 Wait starting for 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 19.91 Wait starting for 
06-04 16:17:38.414 W/ResourceType(26420): getEntry failing because entryIndex 129 is beyond type entryCount 1
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 20.77 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 20.77 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
06-04 16:17:39.119 I/mono-stdout(26420): MvxBind:Warning: 20.77 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
[0:] 
==> Rendered UI in ms 2248
[0:] ==> Rendered UI in ms 2248
06-04 16:17:39.204 I/mono-stdout(26420): ==> Rendered UI in ms 2248
06-04 16:17:40.379 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-04 16:17:41.324 D/AbsListView(26420): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
06-04 16:17:41.329 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called

SECOND RUN (271 ms)

06-04 16:19:53.624 D/AbsListView(26420): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
06-04 16:19:53.624 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-04 16:19:53.649 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-04 16:19:54.044 E/ViewRootImpl(26420): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:158.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:158.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
06-04 16:19:57.249 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:158.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] 
06-04 16:19:57.664 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Attempting to load new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Adding subscription 4efbcbd0-c623-48ab-9172-108d6ae0b036 for ArticleEditDoneMsg
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Adding subscription 4efbcbd0-c623-48ab-9172-108d6ae0b036 for ArticleEditDoneMsg
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:159.33 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
06-04 16:19:57.669 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:159.32 Adding subscription 4efbcbd0-c623-48ab-9172-108d6ae0b036 for ArticleEditDoneMsg
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:159.33 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
06-04 16:19:57.674 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:159.33 Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage
[0:] 
mvx:Warning:159.35 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
[0:] mvx:Warning:159.35 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:19:57.699 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Warning:159.35 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
[0:] 
mvx:Warning:159.36 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
[0:] mvx:Warning:159.36 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
06-04 16:19:57.714 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Warning:159.36 using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507
Thread started:  #8
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:159.46 Wait starting for 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:159.46 Wait starting for 
06-04 16:19:57.814 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:159.46 Wait starting for 
Thread started:  #9
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:159.50 Wait starting for 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:159.50 Wait starting for 
06-04 16:19:57.849 I/mono-stdout(26420): mvx:Diagnostic:159.50 Wait starting for 
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning:159.62 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:159.62 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
06-04 16:19:57.969 I/mono-stdout(26420): MvxBind:Warning:159.62 Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
[0:] 
==> Rendered UI in ms 271
[0:] ==> Rendered UI in ms 271
06-04 16:19:57.984 I/mono-stdout(26420): ==> Rendered UI in ms 271
06-04 16:19:58.054 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-04 16:19:58.279 D/AbsListView(26420): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
06-04 16:19:58.279 D/AbsListView(26420): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Comment: Could you add some code to show us what you are doing?  Why don't you want to Data bind using the normal Android XML files?  That's the best part!  And to be clear you are saying you don't get this delay if you comment out the binding logic?

Comment: Please refer to edited post. To answer your question "why not using xml" it's because i'm working on an enterprise app and i have a fair bit of those "master data" layout to generate. Creating a base class with layout generation functions and then calling them in OnCreate seems to get the job done faster (I was inspired by the Mvx Conference sample which generates read-only layouts based on properties - the difference is that my layout is for editable properties).

Comment: Hmm I don't see anything of the bat.  Could you add the error trace?

Comment: I fixed the intermittent issue I had with tasks, I was not returning the task after ContinueWith. `task.ContinueWith` should be `task = task.ContinueWith`. Now it is working fine but the first time load delay is still noticeable. I did not see much improvement from implementing binding on separate task.

Comment: And you're sure its the binding?  Is it faster if you comment out the binding logic?

Comment: The whole `OnCreate` is taking 1200 ms on the first run, drops to 450ms in the second run and subsequent runs it takes around 200ms.
The call to `set.Apply()` alone is taking 300ms in the first run!
I have also tried replacing an often used label (new Textview) with an inflated version of an xml layout (xml with Textview only). To my surprise the code is slower - I tried that because I read that android is caching the xml layouts - does not seem to help in my case.

Comment: Do you have any weird stuff in your debug trace?

Comment: Just updated the post with the debug trace. Your starting point is `mvx:Diagnostic:158.89 Showing ViewModel ArticleDetailViewModel`
Could it be it's trying to load libraries on the first run... how do I preload these libraries to optimise the load time???

Comment: It does look like it's library load time - in which case: 1. Make sure you test/time in release mode and 2. you can force the libraries to be preloaded by accessing required methods during an early bit of your app - e.g. during Setup or App Initialize